# How would I create a function in Google Docs (or Excel) to evaluate column a and return column b value.

Tags: google-workspace, worksheet-function

I'm using google docs speadsheets to create a dashboard. I have two columns of data. I want to have a cell evaluate Column One for a specific name(for example, "Agency A") and return the value in Column Two that is associated with that agency. I've tried a couple of different things, but my thinking is all off I think.

- **Column 1 Column 2**
- Agency A Value A
- Agency B Value B

In this case, I would want it would return Value A if it finds Agency A in Column 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is a lookup by vertical index, where the key value is in column 1 and the value in column 2. **Excel** supports this via the `VLOOKUP` function. If column 1 = column A, column 2 = column B and the value to look up = C1:

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,$A:$B,2,FALSE)
```

will return the associated value, as in this screenshot:

[image: VLOOKUP formula example screenshot]

You can also restrict the range being looked up if the columns contain other values, i.e. use `A1:B2` (but then be careful of rows being missed when you add key value pairs).

According to [its documentation](https://docs.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=table.cs&topic=25273), **Google Spreadsheets** supports the `VLOOKUP` formula with the same syntax as Excel, so you should be fine there too.

Comment: I forgot to set FALSE for exact match on lookup in the formula. Amended.

Comment: This is what I ended up with for my code. Thanks so much: `=(VLOOKUP(A1,'A-D/A'!A:K,4)-VLOOKUP(A1,'A-D/A'!A:K,5))/VLOOKUP(A1,'A-D/A'!A:K,4)`

Comment: Actually, this is the code: `=(VLOOKUP(A1,'A-D/A'!A:K,4,FALSE)-VLOOKUP(A1,'A-D/A'!A:K,5,FALSE))/VLOOKUP(A1,'A-D/A'!A:K,4,FALSE)`

Comment: Looks like you got this figured out. Glad if my answer helped.

Comment: This will help a County department have a dashboard to evaluate their quality improvement progress; so, this will help many people. Folks in my office are stunned about how quickly we got an answer. I think I've made some converts to stackexchange. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Doubly glad then :).